# SQL, problem with OrderBy / GroupBy

Tags: sql, oracle

In my table I have two fields among others : `article_id` and `version`

Example:

```
   article_id | version
   -----------|----------   
        5     |   1
        5     |   2
        6     |   1
```

**What I want to do is to retrieve the latest version for each article id**. (In my example I want to retrieve the article 5 version 2 object and article 6 and version 1 object).

The problem is that mysql is doing the `group by` instead of the `order by` so it returns to me the FIRST version of each article, but I want the opposite.

Do you have an idea please ?

**Solution**

```
select *
from article r
where r.version=(
 select max(version) 
 from article r2 
 where r2.article_id = r.article_id
);
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM ressources ORDER BY version DESC GROUP BY article_id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit *vague*, but I believe is is more or less this what you want:

```
select * from (
   select
      <table>.*,
      row_number() over (partition by article_id order by version desc) r  
   from 
      <table>
)
where r = 1
```

The query returns one record for each (distinct) article_id. This record is the one with the highest version for the article_id returned.

So, together with a "test case", this can be seen in action:

```
create table tq84_resorces (
  id           number primary key,
  article_id   number not null,
  version      number not null
);

insert into tq84_resorces values (50, 5, 1);
insert into tq84_resorces values (60, 5, 2);
insert into tq84_resorces values (70, 6, 1);


select * from (
   select
      tq84_resorces.*,
      row_number() over (partition by article_id order by version desc) r  
   from 
      tq84_resorces
)
where r = 1
```

which returns:

```
        ID ARTICLE_ID    VERSION          R
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        60          5          2          1
        70          6          1          1
```

Comment: Ok, i never saw such syntax :). Anyway i found a decent solution (see my edit.) Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: @Tristan: The row_number() method is really the only way you should approach this.  The self-join methods may be common in other databases but in Oracle it's not a very good solution.  Analytic functions are much faster and even much simpler when you get used to them.

Answer (score 2):

```
select yt.id, yt.article_id, yt.version
    from (select article_id, max(version) as max_version
              from YourTable
              group by article_id) t
        inner join YourTable yt
            on t.article_id = yt.article_id
                and t.max_version = yt.version
```

Comment: It returns me the wrong ID but the right article_id and version

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    article_id,
    max(version) as Version

from article

group by article_id
```

Comment: It returns me the wrong ID but the right article_id and version

Comment: What do you mean "the wrong ID but right article_id and version"?

Comment: it returns : id: 5 (bad) / article_id : 5 (good) / version: 2 (good)

Comment: the correct id matching article_id 5 and version 2 is 3 and not 5. That's what i meant :)

Comment: @Tristan: You never mentioned an `ID` column. Using this approach will *only* give the correct `article_id` and `version` column. I could give a SQL Server-compliant query using `row_number()`, but I don't know how to deal with ranking/row numbering in Oracle, which is what you'd have to do. Why do you need the `ID` column?

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't know specifying that an ID column was important because it's so natural to me to use it :-). I need to know the ID of the rows because i'm using doctrine and to fetch object i need the id :-). You could give it for mysql, doctrine will handle the oracle part :-)

Comment: @Tristan: Can you not fetch the object based upon `article_id` and `version`? Surely you wouldn't have the same `article_id` and `version` in the same table twice, would you?

Comment: Yeah, article_id + version are unique :-). Thanks for helping you put me on a lead ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you should change the version column into integer (maybe with a prefix column if you strongly need the String), than you are able to

```
Select MAX(version) 
...
Group By article_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this work:

```
select articleId, (select top 1 version 
                  from article ar2 
                  where ar2.articleId = ar.articleId
                  order by version desc) as version
from article ar
group by ar.articlId
```

Works in sql server 2005, did not test in mysql.

Comment: ergh, it must be Oracle compliant, i totally forgot that. and Top is not oracle compliant :o

Comment: Sorry missed the oracle part.

Comment: my bad, i tagged it as mysql :)